# how to restrict access to uploaded files using cck file field from other users

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, file, cck, restrict

I've a node type created by different users who will be uploading private files.
Now all of whom land in sites/default/files folder which has public access and is visible to the world.
I've tried Private Download module but it can't restrict other users to access one's uploaded files.

I'm using Drupal 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't use the filefield module, but [User Files](http://drupal.org/project/user_files) allows making files private except to the uploading user.

EDIT:
[filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) may work for you.  It will allow you to create a folder and only allow that user to access it.  I haven't played around with it too much, but it can definitely be a useful tool.

Comment: This module is still in beta and only 15 sites in the world seem to be using it. I don't want to use it on my production site. Yes I'm looking for module of this type of functionality. One should be able to download/view one's own uploaded files, not others

Comment: @user See my edit for another suggested module, not sure if it will do _exactly_ what you need, but should work

Comment: Is there any configuration for User Files module?